# How to run multiple linux commands as a sequence of arguments through subprocess.Popen Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

code-1 : Passing linux commands as a sequence of arguments

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

run_cmd = Popen(['ls','-l','mkdir','hello'], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
output,error = run_cmd.communicate()
print error,output, run_cmd.returncode
```

**Output - 1:**

```
ls: cannot access mkdir: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
 2
```

In the above code I am trying to run multiple linux commands by passing them as a  sequence of arguments. If I am modifying the above code to the following one it works fine.

code-2 : Pass linux commands as a string

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

run_cmd = Popen('mkdir hello; ls -l; echo Hello; rm -r hello', shell=True, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
output,error = run_cmd.communicate()
print error,output, run_cmd.returncode
```

**Output - 2 :**

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 sujatap sujatap    6 May  9 21:28 hello
-rw-rw-r--. 1 sujatap sujatap   53 May  8 20:51 test.py
Hello
0
```

As `shell=True` is not a suggested way to be used so I want to run the linux commands using the former one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something does not work, check its documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

> **args should be a sequence of program arguments** or else a single string. By default, the program to **execute** is **the first item in args** if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

So test your single program runs first (list of program and its arguments), then make a list of lists and run them in sequence with a loop:

```
myprogramsequence = [
    ["ls", "-l"],
    ["mkdir", "hello"]
]

for argumentlist in myprogramsequence:
    run_cmd = Popen( argumentlist, ...
```

Comment: Note the wording: it does not have to be a `list`, but could be any [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: Thanks for the approach. If I try this method multiple commands are run parallely. Yeah I got the point of sequence.

Comment: That's because it does not wait for the new process to finish. Look if one of the subprocess _convenience functions_ does what you need (same link, a bit further up on the page).

Comment: The underlying of the convenience functions uses Popen. So I will go with that.

Comment: If you want to use Popen directly, [`Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) is for you.

Comment: I get it, that this was chosen as the "solution" because there does not seem to be a proper way to do this in one process. However, this creates other issues. What if you need to change directories between the commands? If you start a new subprocess every time, the current directory of the previous subprocess executing the previous of the commands will be lost. Or anything else that is created or set in the environment of the subprocess. It is far from a universal solution to the problem.

Comment: This is also problematic, when you want to live output subprocess' output, because `Popen.communicate()` is blocking (waiting for a command to be finished and the subprocess to be finished).